# ajax call is not working for deleting record

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to delete record from database using Ajax call in my MVC application. Following is the code for the function calling Ajax call.

```
<script>
    function deleteRow(item, mdkey) {
        var r = confirm("Want to Delete Record?");
        if (r) {
            var row = item.parentNode.parentNode;

            for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                cellname = col.firstChild.name;
                if (cellname == "md_seqno") {
                    var seqno = col.firstChild.value; 
                } 
            }

            if (mdkey != '0') {

                $.ajx({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Session("baseurl")/ContainerManifest/DeleteDetail",
                    data: { md_key: mdkey, md_seqno: seqno },
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert("data is deleted");
                    }

                })

            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
            }

        }


</script>
```

Following is code for my function in controller

```
Public Function DeleteDetail(md_key As String, md_seqno As Integer) As JsonResult

            Dim result As Boolean = True

            OpenDBConnection()
            DBCmd = Globals.oraConnection.CreateCommand

            DBCmd.Parameters.Add("P_MD_KEY", OracleType.Char, 10).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            DBCmd.Parameters("P_MD_KEY").Value = md_key

            DBCmd.Parameters.Add("P_MD_SEQNO", OracleType.Number, 10).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            DBCmd.Parameters("P_MD_SEQNO").Value = md_seqno

            DBCmd.CommandText = "DELETE_MANIFEST_DETAIL"
            DBCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            DBCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


            CloseDBConnection()

            Return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

        End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo. You've called `$.ajx` instead of `$.ajax`.

Comment: yes thanks i have noticed it and corrected it. after correction it is working fine.